# onPress Navigation not navigating

Tags: react-native

I've added the StackNavigator into the application via another separate AppNavigator.js file. Despite this the app still doesn't navigate but does however compile. The button is clickable but has no action.

Different versions of Expo and React-Native along with different Navigation plugins.

Here is a copy of the AppNavigator.js

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Timer from './Timer';
import Main from './Main';
import Splash from './Splash';

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Timer: {
      screen: Timer
    },
    Splash: {
      screen: Splash
    },
    Main: {
      screen: Main
    }
})
export default AppNavigator;
```

And here is my package.json

```
    { 
      "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.13.1",
    "jest-expo": "26.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "26.0.0",
    "react": "16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react-native": "0.54.0",
    "react-navigation": "1.2.1",
    "@builderx/tab-view": "^0.1.5",
    "@builderx/icons": "^0.1.5",
    "@builderx/utils": "^0.1.6",
    "@builderx/react-native-swiper": "^0.1.5"
  }
}
```

Here is also a copy of the Button responsible for navigation:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Center } from "@builderx/utils";
import Button13 from "../symbols/button13";
import Button5 from "../symbols/button5";
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Image } from "react-native";

export default class Timer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.root}>
        <Button13 style={styles.button13} />
        <Center horizontal>
          <Button5
            style={styles.button5}
            onPress={() => {
              alert("hello");
              this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");
            }}
          />
        </Center>
        <Center horizontal>
          <Image
            source={require("../assets/capture.jpg")}
            style={styles.image}
          />
        </Center>
        <View style={styles.rect}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>[Meditation Name]</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text2}>00:00</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First .

Don's use StackNavigator , is deprecated, use [createStackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html) from React-navigation 3.0 instead

Second

Please show the button code, you should call something like `this.props.navigation.navigate('Main')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The code for the button is here :

<Button5
            style={styles.button5}
            onPress={() => {
              alert("hello");
              this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");
            }}
          />

Also I've installed and added createStackNavigator but I'm not sure how to use the 
AppContainer.

Comment: You use the appcontainer like this `export default  createAppContainer(RootNavigator);` , RootNavigator is the navigator that is the "father" of every other navigator, in your case should be AppNavigator

Answer (score 0):

the button  doesn't have access to the navigation props  and you can't have onPress to a custom component. add the code below to the button file then add it to the button like this then just call this.props.navigation.navigate("Main"); on the nested button of that component

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

export default withNavigation(Button5)
```